# Adding/applying a function to the values of an array based with the input values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the value of a pie chart as the data input changes (by the user).

For context, I currently have 4 parameters called Ativo (5 of them), Quota (each set at 20%, 100% divided by the 5 ativos), Perda potencial (each set at 0 with a max of 100%) and Perda (set initially at 0, but will be cumulative). As perda potencial increases, the Quota will decrease by a ratio of 1:5 and vice-versa (Eg. If perda potencial = 20%, then quota will be at 16%. 1% increase in Perda potencial = 0.2% decrease in Quota)

I'd like to now take the difference between the original quota (20%) and the new quota from the updated value on the input (taking the previous example, this would be 20% - 16% = 4%) and save on the Perda variable. This perda would then be added as a pie slice while the Ativo with the new Quota at 16% would be updated on the pie slice (For example, if we want to change the 1st Ativo and place the values from the previous examples, we would go from 1 out of the 5 pie slices at 20% to 6 pie slices, one with the new quota at 16% and another with perda at 4% and the other 4 pie slices would stay at 20% since they haven't been changed). This perda value would be cumulative, such that if any other Quotas are changed, the perda would sum the values.

The code is updating the graph (increasing the perda potencial% will decrease the quota% and change the pie slice values after pressing the button), but the pie slice added for perda is basically the value of the last quota changed and not the difference between the original quota and the new quota.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>


        <div class="table">
            <form id="form">
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td">Ativo </div>
                    <div class="td">Quota % </div>
                    <div class="td">Perda Potencial % </div>
                </div>

                <form id="ativo1test" value="teste"></form>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="TSLA" class="stock" id="ativo1"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota1"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda1" /> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="AAPL" class="stock" id="ativo2"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota2"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda2" /> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="MSFT" class="stock" id="ativo3"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota3"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda3" /> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="EURUSD" class="stock" id="ativo4" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota4" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda4" /> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="BITCOIN" class="stock" id="ativo5"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota5"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda5" /></div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="drawChart();">Desenhar Gráfico</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

        <script>
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Get all the values for each stock input and the quota variation (as "Perda potencial" increases, Quota decreases by a ratio of 1:5 and vice-versa)

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Create arrays so that we can use a for loop (not sure if this would work?) and update the values as the input is changed by the user


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            document.querySelector(".table").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
                const tgt = e.target;
                if (tgt.classList.contains("perda")) {
                    perda = tgt.closest(".tr").querySelector(".quota").value =
                        20 - tgt.value * 0.2;

                    // quota * perda potencial; var = quota * +- perda potencial / 100
                    //quota - var;
                    //let var = perda/risco potencial
                    //console.log(20 - perda);

                    //isto teria que atualizar sempre que a perda potencial % aumenta ou diminui. Neste momento, apenas faz a soma, nao retira o valor quando perda potencial % diminui e a quota aumenta
                }
            });

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Create a "Perda" (Loss) variable that contains the inverse of "Quota". Example: If "Perda potencial" is at 20%, then our "Quota" will be at 16% and our "Perda" would be at 4% (20-16 = 4; original quota - updated quota = perda). This variable should be cumulative so that it will sum up the values for each alteration on the "Quota %" of each "Ativo" (Stock);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Load google chart graphs

            google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Function that will be passed by the "Desenhar grafico" button so that everytime the user clicks the button, it takes the new input values and updates the pie chart
            let perda;

            function drawChart() {

                let ativo1 = document.getElementById("ativo1").value;
                let ativo2 = document.getElementById("ativo2").value;
                let ativo3 = document.getElementById("ativo3").value;
                let ativo4 = document.getElementById("ativo4").value;
                let ativo5 = document.getElementById("ativo5").value;
                let ativosArray = [ativo1, ativo2, ativo3, ativo4, ativo5];

                let quota1 = document.getElementById("quota1").value;
                let quota2 = document.getElementById("quota2").value;
                let quota3 = document.getElementById("quota3").value;
                let quota4 = document.getElementById("quota4").value;
                let quota5 = document.getElementById("quota5").value;
                let quotaArray = [quota1, quota2, quota3, quota4, quota5];

                for (let i = 0; i < quotaArray.length; i++) {
                    perda == quotaArray[i].value;

                };

                console.log(perda)

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn("string", "Ativo");
                data.addColumn("number", "Quota");
                data.addRows([
                    [ativo1, parseFloat(quota1)],
                    [ativo2, parseFloat(quota2)],
                    [ativo3, parseFloat(quota3)],
                    [ativo4, parseFloat(quota4)],
                    [ativo5, parseFloat(quota5)],
                    ["Perda", parseFloat(perda)],
                ]);
                var options = {
                    title: "Calculadora",
                    pieHole: 0.3,
                    pieSliceText: 'value',
                    is3D: true,

                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
                    document.getElementById("piechart")
                );

                chart.draw(data, options);

                console.log(ativo1)
                console.log(quota1);

            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        </script>
</body>


<style>
    .td {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the code that calculates `perda`. Your question is overly long, so I may have misunderstood your intent. Feel free to clarify.

This

```
perda == quotaArray[i].value;
```

...will just evaluate to `true` or `false` as it's an expression. Maybe you meant to use `=`, that means assignment?

Regardless, that doesn't solve your problem. I think you want one pie slice called `Perda` that is a `100` - `sum of all others`. So, you can evaluate it like this

```
let sum = 0.0;
for (let i = 0; i < quotaArray.length; i++) {
  sum += parseFloat(quotaArray[i]);
};
perda = 100.0 - sum;
```

A working snippet with this modification.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>


    <div class="table">
      <form id="form">
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Ativo </div>
          <div class="td">Quota % </div>
          <div class="td">Perda Potencial % </div>
        </div>

        <form id="ativo1test" value="teste"></form>
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="TSLA" class="stock" id="ativo1" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota1" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda1" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="AAPL" class="stock" id="ativo2" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota2" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda2" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="MSFT" class="stock" id="ativo3" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota3" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda3" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="EURUSD" class="stock" id="ativo4" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota4" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda4" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="BITCOIN" class="stock" id="ativo5" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota5" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda5" /></div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="drawChart();">Desenhar Gráfico</button>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

    <script>
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //Get all the values for each stock input and the quota variation (as "Perda potencial" increases, Quota decreases by a ratio of 1:5 and vice-versa)

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //Create arrays so that we can use a for loop (not sure if this would work?) and update the values as the input is changed by the user


      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      document.querySelector(".table").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        const tgt = e.target;
        if (tgt.classList.contains("perda")) {
          perda = tgt.closest(".tr").querySelector(".quota").value =
            20 - tgt.value * 0.2;

          // quota * perda potencial; var = quota * +- perda potencial / 100
          //quota - var;
          //let var = perda/risco potencial
          //console.log(20 - perda);

          //isto teria que atualizar sempre que a perda potencial % aumenta ou diminui. Neste momento, apenas faz a soma, nao retira o valor quando perda potencial % diminui e a quota aumenta
        }
      });

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //Create a "Perda" (Loss) variable that contains the inverse of "Quota". Example: If "Perda potencial" is at 20%, then our "Quota" will be at 16% and our "Perda" would be at 4% (20-16 = 4; original quota - updated quota = perda). This variable should be cumulative so that it will sum up the values for each alteration on the "Quota %" of each "Ativo" (Stock);

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //Load google chart graphs

      google.charts.load("current", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //Function that will be passed by the "Desenhar grafico" button so that everytime the user clicks the button, it takes the new input values and updates the pie chart
      let perda;

      function drawChart() {

        let ativo1 = document.getElementById("ativo1").value;
        let ativo2 = document.getElementById("ativo2").value;
        let ativo3 = document.getElementById("ativo3").value;
        let ativo4 = document.getElementById("ativo4").value;
        let ativo5 = document.getElementById("ativo5").value;
        let ativosArray = [ativo1, ativo2, ativo3, ativo4, ativo5];

        let quota1 = document.getElementById("quota1").value;
        let quota2 = document.getElementById("quota2").value;
        let quota3 = document.getElementById("quota3").value;
        let quota4 = document.getElementById("quota4").value;
        let quota5 = document.getElementById("quota5").value;
        let quotaArray = [quota1, quota2, quota3, quota4, quota5];

        let sum = 0.0;
        for (let i = 0; i < quotaArray.length; i++) {
          sum += parseFloat(quotaArray[i]);
        };
        perda = 100.0 - sum;

        console.log(perda)

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "Ativo");
        data.addColumn("number", "Quota");
        data.addRows([
          [ativo1, parseFloat(quota1)],
          [ativo2, parseFloat(quota2)],
          [ativo3, parseFloat(quota3)],
          [ativo4, parseFloat(quota4)],
          [ativo5, parseFloat(quota5)],
          ["Perda", perda],
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: "Calculadora",
          pieHole: 0.3,
          pieSliceText: 'value',
          is3D: true,

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
          document.getElementById("piechart")
        );

        chart.draw(data, options);

        console.log(ativo1)
        console.log(quota1);

      }

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    </script>
</body>


<style>
  .td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

An example of how I would use for loops to simplify the same code. Also, use the stack snippet to my full advantage to reduce the amount of clutter for the reader. Of-course, you can consider using other Array methods like `reduce`, `forEach`.

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Get all the values for each stock input and the quota variation (as "Perda potencial" increases, Quota decreases by a ratio of 1:5 and vice-versa)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Create arrays so that we can use a for loop (not sure if this would work?) and update the values as the input is changed by the user


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

document.querySelector(".table").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("perda")) {
    perda = tgt.closest(".tr").querySelector(".quota").value =
      20 - tgt.value * 0.2;

    // quota * perda potencial; var = quota * +- perda potencial / 100
    //quota - var;
    //let var = perda/risco potencial
    //console.log(20 - perda);

    //isto teria que atualizar sempre que a perda potencial % aumenta ou diminui. Neste momento, apenas faz a soma, nao retira o valor quando perda potencial % diminui e a quota aumenta
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Create a "Perda" (Loss) variable that contains the inverse of "Quota". Example: If "Perda potencial" is at 20%, then our "Quota" will be at 16% and our "Perda" would be at 4% (20-16 = 4; original quota - updated quota = perda). This variable should be cumulative so that it will sum up the values for each alteration on the "Quota %" of each "Ativo" (Stock);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Load google chart graphs

google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function that will be passed by the "Desenhar grafico" button so that everytime the user clicks the button, it takes the new input values and updates the pie chart
let perda;

function drawChart() {
  const slices = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    slices.push({
      ativo: document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`).value,
      quota: parseFloat(document.getElementById(`quota${i}`).value)
    })
  }

  let sum = 0.0;
  for (let i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
    sum += slices[i].quota;
  };
  perda = 100.0 - sum;

  console.log(perda)

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn("string", "Ativo");
  data.addColumn("number", "Quota");
  data.addRows([
    ...slices.map(slice => ([slice.ativo, slice.quota])),
    ["Perda", perda],
  ]);
  var options = {
    title: "Calculadora",
    pieHole: 0.3,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    is3D: true,

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById("piechart")
  );

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```css
.td {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="table">
    <form id="form">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Ativo </div>
        <div class="td">Quota % </div>
        <div class="td">Perda Potencial % </div>
      </div>

      <form id="ativo1test" value="teste"></form>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="TSLA" class="stock" id="ativo1" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota1" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda1" /> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="AAPL" class="stock" id="ativo2" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota2" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda2" /> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="MSFT" class="stock" id="ativo3" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota3" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda3" /> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="EURUSD" class="stock" id="ativo4" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota4" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda4" /> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="BITCOIN" class="stock" id="ativo5" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota5" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
        <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda5" /></div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" onclick="drawChart();">Desenhar Gráfico</button>
    </form>

  </div>
  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It is working :) I was also trying to use the reduce like this:
let quotaArray = [quota1, quota2, quota3, quota4, quota5];
   const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue;
   let totalSum;

   function total() {
    totalSum = quotaArray.reduce(reducer);
    return reducer
   }; but I couldn't manage to put it to work. I'll take a look at the loop as well! There are a lot of things about javascript I'm not aware of (such as the map you're using) so it will be really helpful to learn new methods! Thank you